# How to bind a JSON data to String in Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard

My service consumes a Json data. I want to bind this into a String. I tried the following code but unsuccessful:

```
@POST
@Path("file/save")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JsonResponse save(String content) {
}
```

I got the error: "Error 400 Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token"
How could I fix this problem?

Comment: can you post a sample of your json string

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a container class for your request and then using that class as a parmeter in your resource method. For example:

```
Class MyRequest {
    public String name;
    public String address;
}

@POST
@Path("file/save")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JsonResponse save(MyRequest req) {
     //req.name, req.address
}
```

If that doesn't work for you, can you give more details on what you are trying to achieve?